# Ionic2-Long Polling: killing http.get request while changing pages

Tags: http, ionic2

My server is developed on Node.js. It is a long-polling service (e.g. chat): it gives the following API:

```
join() //listening for new events
align(fromId) //retrieving events from an id
send(data) //creating an event
```

The long-polling is implemented by the join(): it sends a request and the server answers when there is a new event.

**Front end with Ionic2**

There are 2 pages: `Page`1 and `Page2`. Where `Page2` is the viewer of my events, where the long-polling communication is running.

So I start from `Page1` and then I push() the second page `Page2`. Until now everything works fine; but if I pop() the `Page2` and then push() again the `Page2` then I can see that there is still running the `join()` of the previous instance of my `Page2`. This behaviour creates duplicated join(): if I push/pop `Page2` many times I will have many long-polling communication with the server.

So I'm trying to find a way to kill the `join()` instance, which is a HTTP.get request, when leaving the page.

Let's see now my code.
This is the provider of my Ionic2 in charge of the communication with the server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class MyProvider {
    ...

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.token_access = null;
        this.token_room = null;
    }

    ...

    join(){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('x-access-token',this.getToken());
        return Observable.create(observer =>{
            this.http.get('/localhost/chat/'+this.room,{headers : headers})
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(
                        data=>{                         
                            observer.next(data);
                        },
                        (err) =>{
                            observer.error(err);
                        }
                    );
        })
    }

    send(message){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('x-access-token',this.getToken());
        headers.append('x-chat-token',this.getRoomToken());
        return Observable.create(observer =>{
            this.http.post('/localhost/chat/'+this.room+'/send', JSON.stringify({
                            event: message
                        }),{headers : headers})
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(
                        data=>{
                            observer.next(data);
                        },
                        (err) =>{
                            observer.error(err);
                        }
                    );
        })
    }

    align(from){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('x-access-token',this.getToken());
        headers.append('x-chat-token',this.getRoomToken());
        return Observable.create(observer =>{
            this.http.post('/localhost/chat/'+this.room+'/align', JSON.stringify({
                            fromId: from
                        }),{headers : headers})
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(
                        data=>{
                            observer.next(data);
                        },
                        (err) =>{
                            observer.error(err);
                        }
                    );
        })
    }
}
```

The `Page1` just push the `Page2` with a button that calls the the following code (page1.ts):

```
...
export class Page1 {
    ...

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public myProviderService: MyProvider) {

    }

.....


toPage2(){
        this.navCtrl.push(Page2);
    }
```

And my `Page2` is implemented by the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyProvider } from '../../providers/myprovider';
import { Event } from '../../components/event';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html'
})
export class ChatPage {
    eventsList: Array<Event>;
    message: any;
    last_event: any;
    msg: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public myProviderService: MyProvider) {
        this.last_event = -1;
        this.join();
        this.eventsList= new Array();
  }

  join(){
    this.myProviderService.join().subscribe(
        (data)=>{
            if(data.success){
                this.last_event = this.last_event + 1;
                if(this.last_event == data.event.id){
                    //up to now all events are correctly received
                    this.eventsList.push(data.event);
                }else{
                    //some events are missing
                    this.last_event = this.last_event - 1;
                    this.align();
                }
                this.join();
            }else{
                this.message=data.message;
                //TBD sleep....
                //this.join();
            }
        },
        (err) => {
            this.message="Connectivity with server Lost...";
            //TBD sleep....
            //this.join();
        });
  }

  align(){
    this.myProviderService.align(this.last_event + 1).subscribe((data)=>{
        if(data.success){
            for (var i=0;i<data.events.length;i++) {
                this.eventsList.push(new Event(data.events[i].id,data.events[i].data,data.events[i].user));
                this.last_event = this.last_event + 1;
            };
        }else{
            this.message=data.message;
        }
    },
    (err) => {
        this.message="Failure receiving messages";
    });
  }

  send(): void{
        this.myProviderService.send(this.msg).subscribe((data)=>{
            if(data.success){
                this.msg='';
            }else this.message=data.message;
        },
        (err) => {
            this.message="Error while authenticating";
        })
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
    }

}
```

**So coming back to my question:**
How can I kill the `join()` (kill the HTTP.get request) instance of my Page2 when this is not used, in order to prevent duplicated `join()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you have a provider that is globally added to Providers section of your app (meaning that it can act as a [Singleton service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387855/singletons-in-ionic-3-angular-4)), then you can use the following:

1. Every time Page 2 calls the join() method of your provider check a hasAlreadyJoined boolean variable in your provider.
2. This variable is set to true every time the join() method is called.
3. If the join() has not been called, call it and update the variable accordingly.

So, even though every time Page 2 calls the join() method of MyProvider, this method does the actual http request only if hasAlreadyJoined is false.

For you to be sure that every time a MyProvider instance is initiated it's variables are "static", the provider should be declared at the *global* Providers section of your app module file, not at the *page's* providers section.